# Why "++" works but "::" doesn't work even though they have same logic in scala

Tags: scala, generics

```
abstract class MyList[+A] {
    def head: A
    def next: MyList[A]
    def isEmpty: Boolean
    def add[B >: A](element: B): MyList[B]
    def printElements: String
    override def toString: String = s"[$printElements]"
    def ++[B >: A](list: MyList[B]): MyList[B]
    def ::[B >: A](list: MyList[B]): MyList[B]
}

case object Empty extends MyList[Nothing] {
    def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException
    def next: MyList[Nothing] = throw new NoSuchElementException
    def isEmpty: Boolean = true
    def add[B >: Nothing](element: B): MyList[B] = Cons(element, Empty)
    def printElements: String = ""
    def ++[B >: Nothing](list: MyList[B]): MyList[B] = list
    def ::[B >: Nothing](list: MyList[B]): MyList[B] = list
}

case class Cons[+A](h: A, t: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A] {
    def this(h: A) = this(h, Empty)
    def head: A = h
    def next: MyList[A] = t
    def isEmpty: Boolean = false
    def add[B >: A](element: B): MyList[B] = Cons(element, this)
    def printElements: String =
        if (t.isEmpty) s"$h"
        else s"$h ${t.printElements}"

    def ++[B >: A](list: MyList[B]): MyList[B] = Cons(h, next ++ list)
    def ::[B >: A](list: MyList[B]): MyList[B] = Cons(h, next :: list)
}

object runTest extends App {
    val a = Empty.add(1).add(2).add(3)
    val b = Empty.add(4).add(5).add(6)
    println(a)
    println(b)
    println(a ++ b) //[3 2 1 6 5 4] good
    println(a :: b) //[6 3 5 2 4 1] why???
}
```

I tried to concat two MyList, but the problem is,
"++" and "::" have the same logic
but "++" will print [3 2 1 6 5 4], which makes sense, while "::" will prints [6 3 5 2 4 1]

Comment: `::` should prepend a single element, `++` should append another `List` and `:::` should prepend another `List`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [2.13 language specifications](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#infix-operations) (I can't seem to find the scala3 version, but this part hasn't changed):

> Operators ending in a colon ‘:’ are
> right-associative. All other operators are left-associative.

[...]

> If `op` is right-associative and its parameter is passed by name, the same operation is interpreted as `e2.op(e1)`

---

So your `a :: b` is the same as `b.::(a)`, and

```
def ::[B >: A](list: MyList[B]): MyList[B] = Cons(h, next :: list)
```

is

```
def ::[B >: A](list: MyList[B]): MyList[B] = Cons(h, list.::(next))
```

which explains the `[6 3 5 2 4 1]` you're getting.

You can get the result you want by using

```
def ::[B >: A](list: MyList[B]): MyList[B] = Cons(h, next.::(list))
...
println(a.::(b))
```